# Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot set property 'status'

Tags: javascript, json, ajax, vue.js, axios

Hey ya'll I'm having some issues trying to confirm the response I'm receiving from my server using Axios with VueJS

```
axios.post('/login', {
  email: this.email,
  password: this.password
}).then(response => {
  if (response.status == 200) {
    $root.$data.auth = true;
  } else {
    alert('uhhhh');
  }
}).catch(e => {
  if (e.response.status == 422) {
    this.error = "You made that login right?  How could you habve forgotten it!";
  } else {
    this.error = "Something else happened and this is what: " + e.response.status;
  }
});
```

On successful logins I see this in the console:

`Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot set property 'status' of undefined`

Which seems confusing as the Axios documentation states I can pull the response.status object and run conditional logic from it?

Comment: the error says cannot set, here you are only reading the status property, where are your updating the status?

Comment: That's what's also making this weird as the only mention of status in that component is trying to read that response object. :/

Comment: do you have anywhere else in the code a statement `.status = something`

Comment: Can you show us the line of code from which the exception was emitted?

Comment: `if (e.response.status == 422) {` that's where it's squawking in the console.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't check the response status anyway beacuse if isn't 200(OK), the code will execute the next callback that is `.catch()` and here you can handle the error.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get rid of the error.response.status **undefined** error with this:

```
const errStatus = (typeof error.response.status !== 'undefined') ? error.response.status : 'unknown';
const errText = (error.response.statusText != null) ? error.response.statusText : 'unknown';
const errElse = { email: [`[Error status code: ${errStatus}].....[Error status: ${errText}]......Please submit a trouble ticket`] };
this.errors = errElse;
```